# android calendar: how to show only 7 days?

Tags: android, calendarview

im trying to customize a Android CalendarView but i simply cant figure out how to do it. What i want for example is, that the calendar shows only the next 7 days and if you swipe the next 7 days and so on... is that possible? I thought its possible by setting min and maxDate() but that is then set for the whole calendar and you cannot swipe...

i got this:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CalendarView simpleCalendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        simpleCalendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.simpleCalendarView); // get the reference of CalendarView
        simpleCalendarView.setFocusedMonthDateColor(Color.RED); // set the red color for the dates of  focused month
        simpleCalendarView.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(Color.BLUE); // set the yellow color for the dates of an unfocused month
        simpleCalendarView.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // red color for the selected week's background
        simpleCalendarView.setWeekSeparatorLineColor(Color.GREEN); // green color for the week separator line

        // perform setOnDateChangeListener event on CalendarView
        simpleCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                // display the selected date by using a toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

now can i do that in that code or do i have to "draw" the calendar completely by myself or how? :S

thx for the help

Comment: no one?:S i really cant find a solution

Answer (score 5):

I know that it is very late, but you can use the [library MaterialCalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) for this purpose.
Just add it to your layout and set `app:mcv_calendarMode="week"` as an attribute. That's it - only the current week will be displayed and you can swipe through the weeks.

Comment: how can we programmatically change this mode?